# Maven Assembly is not working

Tags: maven

I have a maven project and have written assembly.xml to assemble the package in desired way.
I am able to package my project successfully on my local machine in eclipse but when I checked in the project and Jenkin triggered the build, it's not working at all. After the line

> Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/assembly.xml

The build is not progressing futher.I think it goes into deadlock mode.How to tackle this issue? There is no hint because it runs successfully in Eclipse

Comment: Try this: Log in to your jenkins machine. I suppose it's a linux box? switch to the jenkins user, go to `$HOME/workspace` and look for your project. Then run mvn directly from the command line, potentially with `-X` for debugging. It might yield more info that we can use (consider putting it in pastebin if it's a huge log!)

Comment: Have you taken a look into the target folder of the appropriate build to look if your desired artifact has been build ?

Comment: I do not have right to Log in because it is maintained by our client on one of their servers.And it's Linux Box.